# browser asks to resend data when page is reloaded

Tags: java, jsp, design-patterns, struts2, post-redirect-get

I am writing an application using struts2. I am facing a problem in the login part. When a login is performed,it will redirect to the index.jsp page.Now the problem arises. The problem is when after loggin in, index.jsp is reloaded, browser asks me resend data. I dont know why it is happening? 
here is my struts.xml code for authenticate action:-

```xml
<action name="authenticate" class="com.action.LoginAction">  
    <result name="success">index.jsp</result>
    <result name="failure">loginerror.jsp</result> 
</action>
```

and here is code for the login action class:-

```
public String execute() {
    if(sessionMap.containsKey("project_user")){
        return "success";
    }

    Project_User project_User=Login.checkCredentials(email_id,password);

    if(project_User!=null) {
        sessionMap.put("project_user", project_User);
        return "success";
    } else
        return "failure";
}
```

also when index.jsp comes, the url area of browser remians unchanged, the link in url field of browser still shows the action name like:- localhost:8084/Tek-Hub/authenticate/ 
if anyone knows about it plzzz help me.
Thanxx

Comment: What URL was before  `authenticate`?

Comment: url before authenticate could be anything. Because user can login anytime and anywhere. there is no restriction on user. Thats why url before authenticate could be anything.

Comment: When a user needs to authenticate it should go to the login form and then post their credentials to the login action. The action after processing authentication redirect you back because it knows the previous URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a pattern named [**PRG** (Post / Redirect / Get)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

This way, a second request will be performed when executing the first action result (because of the redirection), and a refresh of the landing page (eg. pressing F5) will hit the second action (the GET one), instead of the login action (the POST one).

Change this:

```xml
<action name="authenticate" class="com.action.LoginAction">  
    <result name="success">index.jsp</result>
    <result name="failure">loginerror.jsp</result> 
</action>
```

to this:

```xml
<action name="authenticate" class="com.action.LoginAction">  
    <result name="success" type="redirectAction">index.action</result>
    <result name="failure">loginerror.jsp</result> 
</action>

<action name="index" class="com.action.IndexAction">  
    <result name="success">index.jsp</result>
</action>
```

[image]